# Tomcat 10 SSL Config issue

Tags: java, tomcat

When I tried to apply SSL for tomcat 10 with the open jdk 17, the SSL is not getting applied whereas i did the same for tomcat 9 with open jdk 17, it works.

```
No SSLHostConfig element was found with the hostName [tntkeystore.jks] to match the defaultSSLHostConfigName for the connector [https-jsse-nio-8443]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:76)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1192)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1205)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1052)
    ... 9 more
```

```java
    private Connector createSecuredConnector() {
            try {
                // Create key store file
                final File file = File.createTempFile(getClass().getName(), ".keystore");
                copyInputStreamToFile(getKeyStoreAsStream(), file);
                // Create connector
                final Connector result = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
                result.setPort(HTTPS_PORT.getIntValue());
                result.setScheme("https");
                result.setSecure(true);
                result.setProperty("maxHttpHeaderSize","12288");
                result.setProperty("defaultSSLHostConfigName","tntkeystore.jks");
                //result.setProperty("compression", "on");
                result.setProperty("compressableMimeType",
                        "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml,application/vnd.ms-fontobject,application/font-sfnt");
                result.setProperty("SSLEnabled", "true");
                result.setProperty("keystoreFile", file.getPath());
                result.setProperty("keystorePass", "axway*");
                result.setProperty("sslProtocol", "TLSv1.2");
                result.setProperty("sslEnabledProtocols", "TLSv1.2");
                result.setProperty("ciphers", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384," +
                        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256," +
                        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384," +
                        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256," +
                        "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA");
                return result;
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Through tomcat 8 the SSL attributes were in the Connector. In 8.5 and 9 they were deprecated in favor of new subelements SSLHostConfig and Certificate to support SNI vhosts, but you can still use them and they 'fall through' to defaulted subelements. In tomcat 10 this is no longer allowed; you _must_ use the subelements. See sixth paragraph at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support .

Comment: SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
   SSLHostConfigCertificate cert =
     new SSLHostConfigCertificate(sslHostConfig, SSLHostConfigCertificate.Type.RSA);
   String filepath=KeyStoreUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
     "tntkeystore.jks").getPath();
   cert.setCertificateKeystoreFile(filepath);
   cert.setCertificateKeystorePassword("test*");
   cert.setCertificateKeyAlias("test");
   sslHostConfig.addCertificate(cert);
   result.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig);

Comment: Added below code to resolve this issue it working fine .